# How to retrieve avaliable versions of a maven dependency programmatically?

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin, versioning, mojo

I want to find all available versions of a dependency in my project using a Mojo. I need this information to create a complete dependency tree where not only the transitive dependencies are included, but also all available versions and then their respective dependencies.

The problem is that I can't simply download each individual metadata file since that would make the plugin too slow. What other ways are there to find all other versions through a Mojo and the Maven plugin API, and how do I achieve it?

Example of tree I'm trying to generate.

[image]

If I only look at the components specified in the pom, I will miss out on the dependency a1.0 -> c1.1 and b1.0 -> d1.1.

To clarify what information I am missing; the following graph shows what would appear if I where to simply use dependency:tree.

[image]

Comment: You know [versions-maven-plugin:display-dependency-updated](http://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/display-dependency-updates-mojo.html) and much more...Apart from that you need to have the metadata otherwise you can't see which versions available of a dependency....

Comment: I've seen that there are for example classes in the Maven API that should support getting the Metadata such as the class "ArtifactRepositoryMetadata". However I've had trouble making this work in practice, probably since I don't know how to do the correct setup. Do you know how to set it up or achieve the same results through any convenient way utilizing the maven API?

Comment: I would suggest to either look at  maven-dependency-plugin or versions-maven-plugin source code...But I would reconsider to think about your approach and would ask why you need all of the dependencies? What kind of problem are you trying to solve ?

Comment: There is no problem that I am trying to solve. I am simply interested in being able to see the complete graph. However, your answer seems to suggest that this is a particularly difficult or impractical thing to do. I have limited knowledge about Maven myself so any guidance would help.

Comment: The point is the tree of dependencies of a state of a project can be shows by using dependency:tree ...The questions which kind of information you are missing ?

Comment: The newer versions can shown by my first comment `versions:display-dependency-updates`....

Comment: The missing information is the newer versions of the dependencies. In the example above, the dependencies (as stated in the POM:s) would be as shown in the new graph I just uploaded.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173820/discussion-between-sk8eddie-and-khmarbaise).